# Atomikos transaction using two database

Tags: jta, xa, atomikos

I have tested Atomikos JTA using single database transaction and works great. But I don't see any examples for transactions across two database. Note: I am using Atomikos standalone API (i.e. not with Spring / Hibernate or other framework).

What I want is write a single transaction that insert/update/commit into two seperate database (Oracle-Oracle for my testing). It performs commit if both are successful or rollback if any exception.

I am looking for any configuration that is required OR sample code for such example.

Really appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no any difference with single DataSource configuration actually. here is the example that i've written in [github](https://github.com/isopov/multiple-ds-tx-test/commit/de979004f5592a51258a6b8f40e3d20babd40373). Be sure that you use XADataSource and not the ordinary DataSource, but this is the same for the single DataSoucre case.